# How to write a parser in prolog to output a parse tree

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

I am writing a parser in prolog that should be able to parse this math formula:

`a = 1 * 2 + (3 - 4) / 5;`

and print out a parse tree out of it that should look like this:

```
 PARSE TREE:
 assignment
    ident(a)
    assign_op
    expression
        term
            factor
                int(1)
            mult_op
            term
                factor
                    int(2)
        add_op
        expression
            term
                factor
                    left_paren
                    expression
                        term
                            factor
                                int(3)
                        sub_op
                        expression
                            term
                                factor
                                    int(4)
                    right_paren
                div_op
                term
                    factor
                        int(5)
    semicolon
```

I have this function that will print out the parse tree when I run the code `run('program1.txt', 'myparsetree1.txt')`. which will read the math formula from the `program1.txt` file and print out the parse tree on the `myparsetree1.txt` file.

So far I have tried writing this grammar for the parser, but isn't working as I keep getting existence and instantiation error mostly with `letter_code` and digit_code from the `tokenizer` whereas `prolog` complains on too few arguments in it among other things.

```
 /*Loads the tokenizer*/
:- [tokenizer].

parse(I) --> assign(I).
assign(assign(I,'=', Expr,';')) -->
        letter_code(I), '=', expr(Expr), ';'.
expr(expr(Term, add_op, Expr)) -->
        term(Term), add_op, expr(Expr).
expr(expr(Term, sub_op, Expr)) -->
        term(Term), sub_op, expr(Expr).
expr(expr(Term)) --> term(Term).        

term(term(Factor, mul_op, Term)) -->
        factor(Factor), mul_op, term(Term). 
term(term(Factor, div_op, Term)) -->
        factor(Factor), div_op, term(Term).
term(term(Factor)) --> factor(Factor).



factor(factor('(', Expr, ')')) --> '(', expr(Expr), ')'.

factor(factor(Digit)) --> digit_code(Digit).

add_op --> ['+'].       
sub_op --> ['-'].
mul_op --> ['*'].
div_op --> ['/'].
```

letter_code and digit_code are predicates from a separate file called tokenizer.pl

```
digit_code(Code):-
    Code >= 48, /* 48 = '0' 57 = '9' */
    Code =< 57.  

letter_code(Code):-
    Code >= 97, /* 97 = 'a' 122 = 'z' */
    Code =< 122.
```

When I run the program I usually get existence error: letter_code/3, same with digit code in which it complains that theere isn't a predicate with 3 arguments. I have tried changing the predicate to have three arguments instead but then I get instantiation error instead. This is what I did and what it results in:

```
letter_code(Code, Xs, Xs):-
    Code >= 97,
    Code =< 122.


| ?- run('program1.txt','myparsetree1.txt').
! Existence error in user:letter_code/1
! procedure user:letter_code/1 does not exist
! goal:  user:letter_code(97)
//------------------------------------------------

letter_code(Code, Xs, Xs):-
    Code >= 97,
    Code =< 122.

letter_code(Code):-
    Code >= 97,
    Code =< 122.


| ?- run('program1.txt','myparsetree1.txt').
! Instantiation error in argument 1 of (>=)/2
! goal:  _293>=97
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I hope I made it clearer than when I first postid this question.

Comment: Prolog does not have functions, Prolog has predicates. Is this class work/home work?

Comment: Are you aware of how [listing/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1) works and why it can help with DCG?

Comment: Kind of a lot of code to process at once, do you have specific error messages for specific calls?

Comment: According to the Stackoverflow guidelines, you need to point out a more specific error under particular conditions. Showing a large amount of code and asking, "Can you help me get this working?" is not a good question.

Comment: The most occuring problem for me is when I run the run('program1.txt', 'myparsetree1.txt') I get existence errror: letter_code/3 where it complains that there isn't a letter_code that uses three arguments even though I called on letter_code with just one argument.

Answer (score 0):

In the DCG body, `letter_code(C)` is going to expand to a call to `letter_code/3`. Your implementation with three arguments doesn't remove anything from the list, so I think this is not likely to have the effect you want, you probably want something like this instead:

```
letter_code(Code) --> 
    [Code], 
    {
        Code >= 97,
        Code =< 122
    }.
```

DCG rules expand to predicates with two extra arguments; for instance, `listing(letter_code//1)` shows this as the parsed value:

```
?- listing(letter_code//1).
letter_code(A, [A|C], B) :-
    A>=97,
    A=<122,
    B=C.

true.
```

When you redefined `letter_code/3` yourself with `letter_code(Code, Xs, Xs) :- ...` you should have made something that would compile but fail at runtime. So your issues with not being able to find predicates that you have clearly defined lie somewhere else.

Comment: Then do you know what the instantiation error I listed above means?

Comment: @IllogicalOverride Yeah, it means you're entering `letter_code` with `Code` as a free variable, not bound to anything.

Comment: When I don't get any errors I will instead just get no when I run the run('program1.txt', 'myparsetree1.txt'). I know that when I ask a query if the rule or fact I am asking about does not exist I will get no but what does it mean here? How do I know what I did wrong?

Comment: @IllogicalOverride actually if you use an undefined predicate in a query you will get an exception about an undefined predicate. Getting ‘no’ is not an error, it means that your query could not be satisfied.

Comment: I use the same code for printing the parse tree like the guy in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878382/how-to-do-a-parser-in-prolog

but with this code at the top

run(InputFile,OutputFile):-
 tokenize(InputFile,Program),
 parse(ParseTree,Program,[]),
 evaluate(ParseTree,[],VariablesOut), 
 output_result(OutputFile,ParseTree,VariablesOut).

however I still get "no" when I try using his parser code which he proclaims to be working already. Can it be that there might be something wrong with the code that will print out the parser?

Comment: @IllogicalOverride I can't see into your machine and debug your code. You're just going to have to debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In DCGs, you embed Prolog code bracketing it:

```
parse(I) --> assign(I).
assign(assign(I,'=', Expr,';')) -->
        {letter_code(I)}, '=', expr(Expr), ';'.
...
```

That is.